# Borland C++ Builder 6 and string concatenation

Tags: string, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm using Borland C++ Builder 6 to try to do some simple string concatenation. However, I have run into what I think is an interesting issue.

Everything I am able to find online states that I should be able to do something as simple as this:

```
String word = "a" + "b" + "c";
```

However, when I try to compile this code, I get an "Invalid pointer addition" error. I could go as far as assigning each part to its own variable and adding each of those together to get the desired output. However, I think that's unnecessary given how simple of an example this is.

The only way I have been able to get something similar to the above to work as desired is by doing this:

```
String a = "";
String word = a + "a" + "b" + "c";
```

My question is this: why would the second example work just fine but not the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the type of `"a"` is `char*` (i.e.: pointer-to-char), which means when you write

```
"a" + "b"
```

you are trying to add to pointers together, which is not allowed.

When you create a `String` type, the `operator+` is overloaded so

```
String a = "";
a + "b"
```

adds a pointer-to-char to a `String`, which has its own defintion of concatenation.

Comment: I see. So basically if I wanted to add strings this way, I should just use the second example provided up there. Even though I view it as strange behavior (I'm normally a C# programmer)

Comment: @hawk4031 - Correct.  You could also use an anonymous String object: `String word = String("a") + "b";`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but this is probably because of arguments. "a" in the first line is `char*`, so adding other strings still makes the result of `char*` and it is not possible to directly assign it o a `String` object. The second case shows, that if the first argument is of `String` type, all results are also Strings, so assignment is possible.