# Function return value from formless or non-form unit

Tags: c++, c++builder

Hi I am not sure how to call function in formless or non-form unit to return the value.

Unit1.h

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TButton *Button2;
    TLabel *Label2;
    void __fastcall Button2Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Unit1.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit3.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    USHORT lengthOfYard;
    USHORT widthOfYard;
    USHORT areaOfYard;

    widthOfYard = 15;
    lengthOfYard = 17;
    areaOfYard= FindArea(lengthOfYard,widthOfYard);
    Label2->Caption = "\nYour yard is "+ areaOfYard +" square feet\n\n";

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unit3.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef Unit3H
#define Unit3H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// declare the function here in the header file.

USHORT FindArea(USHORT length, USHORT width); //function prototype

#endif//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unit3.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit3.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)

USHORT FindArea(USHORT l, USHORT w)
{
    return l * w;
}
```

I could not find solution  or tutorial for this question. 
You have a better one?
Clement

Comment: The current file organization seems fine. Do you have any warning/error messages? What is your concern about?

Comment: In Unit1.cpp, the error is "    Unit1.cpp(29): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *)" for highlighted error "Label2->Caption = "\nYour yard is "+ areaOfYard +" square feet\n\n";". Error happens while compiling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current file organization is fine.

You should change the line:

```
Label2->Caption = "\nYour yard is " + areaOfYard + " square feet\n\n";
```

into:

```
Label2->Caption = "\nYour yard is " + String(areaOfYard) + " square feet\n\n";
```

The first form gives the error:

> E2885: Invalid pointer addition

since the type of `"\nYour yard is "` is `char *` and you are adding a number to a pointer (take a look at [Borland C++ Builder 6 and string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10917797/3235496) and [Concatenate two string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6061648/3235496) for further details).

With a `String` the `operator+` is overloaded and adding a pointer-to-char to a `String` is well defined.

EDIT

[`USHORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#USHORT) type is defined in `windows.h`. You should add:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

in `Unit3.h` or, better, use a standard C++ type (`unsigned FindArea(unsigned l, unsigned w)`).

Comment: Hi Thanks . After I made corrections, then the new error came up. It seemed that I made multiple declarations of only one  function. I am not sure where I made mistake. Error is "[bcc32 Error] Unit3.h(9): E2141 Declaration syntax error
  Full parser context
    Unit3.cpp(5): #include Unit3.h
[bcc32 Error] Unit3.cpp(9): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'USHORT'
[bcc32 Error] Unit3.h(9): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'USHORT'".

Comment: `USHORT` is defined in `windows.h` and probably it's unknown inside `Unit3.cpp` (more details in the answer)... or you've defined your USHORT type somewhere (so multiple declaration).

Comment: Thanks. I changed Ushort to int.